# Laravel data missing on query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I got some missing data from relationship query from specific id
I have 2 tables articles and comment

There is the model
Article :

```
class Article extends Model {
    public $fillable = [
         'title',
         'description',
    ];
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'article_id');
    }
}
```

Comment

```
class Comment extends Model {
     public $fillable = [
           'comment',
           'article_id',
           'user_id',
     ];
     public function article(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Article::class, 'article_id');
     }
}
```

There is my query on getting all articles with comments:

```
Article::with('comments')->get();
```

This return all article but the comments missing; then i tried to update manualy the article_id on  database for the comment table, this return all data well;
The things crazy about it, in others table and their relationships, there is somethink like, in get all, Some row data got his relationship data and other row has no relationship data in the same query while these data exist.
example i got:

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'name',
    comments: [
       {
         id: '1',
         name: 'name',
         article_id: '1'
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'name',
    comments: []
  }
]
```

While in database this object with id 2 have data in his relation, and the object with id 1 get his relation foreign key updated manualy.
I use laravl 6.2, i don't know if it's related

Comment: share your schemas and sample data set.

Comment: can you share your Comment model?